# Javascript: Firefox addon, calling a function inside

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

In my button.xul file I have this:

```
      <script type="application/x-javascript"
  src="chrome://mf_unblocker/content/button.js"/>

<toolbarbutton id="custom-button-1"
  label="Custom"
  tooltiptext="MAFIAAFire: Slash Unblocker!"
  oncommand="CustomButton[1]()"
  class="toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional mf_unblocker"
  />
```

then in my button .js file I have this:

```
var CustomButton = {

1: function () {
alert("test!");
  },

test: function () {alert("testing!");},

}
```

in the xul file this `CustomButton[1]` brings up the alert "test!" but if I change it to `CustomButton[test]` it does not bring up the alert "testing!"

why is that?? It instead gives me an error "test is not define"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the *variable* `test` and not the *string* `"test"`.

`test` is probably `undefined`

Either:

```
CustomButton['test']();
```

or

```
CustomButton.test();
```

Comment: I have to wait 10 mins before being able to accept the answer for some reason ;(